# How can I preserve the state of my website after jQuery is executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, panel, uislider, deep-linking

I have a website that implements jQuery plugins like horizontal sliders and other java script elements. After clicking on link that is towards the right of the website, the page will slide that panel in which the link is contained over and drop down additional text. It will also redirect to another page. I want the user to be able to return to the website exactly as it was seen before redirection.

I looked into deep linking but found it insufficient; from what I've seen it relies on Ajax which I would like to avoid. If it can be done only with jQuery that would be optimal. How could this be implemented?

For reference, I am using the [Spry Sliding Panels](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/samples/slidingpanels/SlidingPanelsSample.html&ei=ZII_ULjOC4-vqAHow4HgDQ&usg=AFQjCNFdiweP13SK4_Gf2dtZrohIOG01xg&sig2=jIaTiG-7EVhuxAkBeEKEdg) to slide to the new panel, and jQuery's slideDown() and after both these actions are clicked I'd like to save the current page's state in the browser's history.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid AJAX? Are you aware that it doesn't require any additional libraries, and AJAX functions are built-in to jQuery?

Comment: @Sparky672 no, and I'm rather unfamiliar with them. How could I use them to do this?

Comment: @Travesty3 that's what I thought, actually. I am an intern, though, and asked if we were using Ajax. He told me we weren't using it and to use just Javascript and jQuery. I'm confused by that.

Comment: [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) stands for Asynchronous Javascript And XML. So AJAX is part of Javascript. It is used to communicate with a server (like you might need to do in order to load a page) without redirecting the browser. And really, it sounds like it would be a good solution for you. It's really not too hard to figure out. You can start out with a tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) and then move on to implementing it with jQuery once you grasp the idea. Trust me, if your future involves Javascript, you'll almost undoubtedly use AJAX at some point.

Comment: @user1274649 JQuery has made it easy to work with Ajax. Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Since the Ajax functions are a part of jQuery, you don't necessarily have to learn native Ajax, although it is certainly helpful. And I agree with Travesty3. If you're going to be working with JS, Ajax will become a large part of your career.

Comment: @user1274649 -- There is this weird thing that happens with some jQuery coders:  jQuery uses a much different syntax from straight Javascript coding that some people learn how to code /only/ in jQuery and don't know how to read straight, simple and ordinary Javascript.  When that happens, they look for a jQuery solution to /every/ problem.  AJAX, by itself, is straight Javascript with help of the browser.  jQuery wraps AJAX up in a different looking syntax, but in the end == jQuery really is "just Javascript" at the end.  Javascript wearing a heavy disguise, though.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I asked some questions to other people on my team and implementing this with Ajax is entirely unnecessary. Instead we will use jQuery.